# Add in between fetch rows

Tags: mysql, fetch

I want to fetch 4 rows from my mysql and add diffrent text after each  row

```
$rel=mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM b_topics WHERE MATCH (subject) AGAINST('$title') LIMIT 4");
if(mysql_num_rows($rel)<0) { 
  echo ""
} 
else {
  echo" <br><strong><div align='center'>Related Topics</div <br>";
  while($rel2=mysql_fetch_assoc($rel)) {
     $gnum=mysql_num_rows($rel2);
     if($gnum==1) {
       echo" yes"
     }
     if($gnum==2) {
        echo" no yes"
     }
     if($gnum==3) {
        echo"yes yes"
     }
     if($gnum==4) {
       echo" wmjayes";
     }
     $reltitle=$rel2["subject"];
     $relid=$rel2["id"];
     echo" <a href='showtopic.php?id= $relid'>$reltitle>$gnum</a><br>";
   }
}
```

Comment: When posting code, please paste it in with all original whitespace/indentation intact, highlight and use the `{}` editor toolbar button or `ctl-k` to format it as a code block.

Comment: What's the issue you face? This is your requirement. Not a question really.

Comment: Please ask a new question rather than modifying an existing question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mysql_fetch_assoc only ever contains one row, counting the number of rows will not work for you. Also, mysql_num_rows tell you how many rows were returned in your query results ($rel), it does not tell you which row you are on.

Instead consider using a counter variable:

```
$rel=mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM b_topics WHERE MATCH (subject) AGAINST('$title') LIMIT 4");
if(mysql_num_rows($rel)<0) { 
  echo ""
} 
else {
  $counter = 0;
  echo "<div style='text-align: center; font-weight: bold; margin: 10px'>Related Topics</div>";
  while($rel2=mysql_fetch_assoc($rel)) {
     $counter++;

     if($counter==1)
       echo" yes";

     elseif($counter==2)
        echo "no yes";

     elseif($counter==3)
        echo "yes yes";

     elseif($counter==4)
       echo" wmjayes";

     $reltitle=$rel2["subject"];
     $relid=$rel2["id"];
     echo" <a href='showtopic.php?id= $relid'>$reltitle>$counter</a><br>";
   }
}
```

Also, to make your code a bit faster consider using `elseif` or `else if` instead of multiple `if` statements. You might also want to look into the PHP `switch` statement for an alternative.

Also, two things you should not do:

1) Do not use mysql functions, either use mysqli or PDO functions. mysql functions in PHP are deprecated and should no longer be used.

2) Do not use `<br>` to add spacing. Also, a block-level element (such as a div) cannot appear in an inline element (such as strong). For both of these use CSS instead. I have modified this for you to use inline CSS but you should eventually place it in an external CSS file.

Comment: @AkshayHegde If you read my answer, you will notice that I mention using the switch statement. I was giving him an answer that was close to his own code and offering him alternative approaches that he could look into.

Comment: No worries.. :)